# JQuery Mobile - Run load () html and navigate () immediately afterwards.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

JQuery Mobile - Run load () html and navigate () immediately afterwards.

I'm implementing a small application using jQuery Mobile where I have a login screen that gives access to a home with menus that lead to a few pages. My question is how can I dynamically load the pages only when I click on the menu.

I tried to do something like

```
$('#home').load('home.html');
$.mobile.navigate("#home");
```

but despite the effect of the load carrying navigate does not work, or does not redirect to the page.

Can anyone give me a hint how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use a callback.  Because `load` is asynchronous, you actually end up calling `$.mobile.navigate` before load has finished.  By sending the next step as a callback, you ensure it happens after you have completed the first step.

From jQuery Documentation:

> If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after
>   post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is
>   fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set
>   to each DOM element in turn.

So your code would look like:

```
$( "#home" ).load( "home.html", function() {
  $.mobile.navigate("#home");
});
```